# how to check datepicker value in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

I want to add **startdate** and **enddate**, so I have created both different **datecontroller class** for both **startdate** and **enddate**.

When I enter first time then my condition is working good and gets saved in data base also in good manner. But **if I update and then I click save message then I get alert message block in my code**. I want that start date must be smaller or equal than enddate value.

This is my code it is working only first time when I was inserting value in database table. **If I update and click save button then its cheking condition and in that value its getting database old value start date and enddate how to solve this issue?**

When I come back I get this on `NSLog`

```
message 2012-08-07 14:21:08.047 People[17111:207] *****:2012-08-06 18:30:00 +0000
2012-08-07 14:22:54.752 People[17111:207] *****:2012-08-06 18:30:00 +0000
```

My code :-

```
-(IBAction)plusSignTapped:(id)sender
{


    NSComparisonResult result = [firstobj.StartDate compare: firstobj.EndDate]; 
    NSLog(@"*****:%@", firstobj.StartDate);
    NSLog(@"*****:%@", firstobj.EndDate);
    if( result == NSOrderedDescending || result==NSOrderedSame) 
    { 
        UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"End date should be greater than or equal to start date " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

      return;   
    } 
}
```

Comment: How you enter date in variables? Through UIDatePicker or enter manually in UITextField?

Comment: i am adding date through datepicker

Comment: Also your ivar name doesn't match Apple Naming Convention **firstobj.StartDate**
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html

Comment: Are your picking up correct values from datepicker??and do your "firstobj.StartDate" and "firstobj.EndDate" get updated when the user chooses them next time??

Comment: firstobj is my modal class variable name i am create first*firstobj fr getting that class variable for value

Comment: my firstobj.startdate is update i can see on tableview cell is printing but i getting problem when i check condition

Answer (score 0):

Let's imaging that we have two dates and two datepickers:

**firstDate**, **secondDate**;

**firstDatePicker**, **secondDatePicker**;

In your **firstDatePicker** function which responsible for the value change event you must set  minimumDate of **secondDatePicker** (and also **date** value, if it's less than minimum date)

```
- (void)firstDatePickerDateChanged
{
    firstDate = firstDatePicker.date
    secondDatePicker.minimumDate = firstDate;
    if ([secondDatePicker.date firstDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        secondDatePicker.date = [firstDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:24 * 3600];
        // we add a day to second date, but you can add any value
        [secondDatePicker sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        // you need send value changed message to update your secondDate var            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this as this is alternative for checking date is less than or equal to date:

```
NSTimeInterval timeStartDate = [firstobj.StartDate timeIntervalSince1970]; //StartDate convert into time
NSTimeInterval timeEndDate = [firstobj.EndDate timeIntervalSince1970]; //EndDate convert into time
if (timeStartDate <= timeEndDate) //Compare StartDatetime with EndDatetime
{
    NSLog(@" timeStartDate less thanORequal to %f timeEndDate :%f", timeStartDate,timeEndDate);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@" Date is greater");
}
```